# Remove extra space

Tags: oracle

I have data like this: `'    999999'`. I want to remove the extra space or whatever the things are before the digits.

In my table the data is of varchar2 type. I have tried replace(), trim(), ltrim(), replace() but nothing worked. Still when I donwload a CSV file from SQL Developer it shows the data like this - `,     9999999,` (having space before digits). But I don't want space or anything coming before the digits.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column name= ltrim(column name) where abc= '13712';
```

Please let me know the solution.

When I pass the data to a `dump()` I get this output:

```
Typ=1 Len=6: 57,57,57,57,57,57
```

---

**Editor's note:** the markdown suppresses the leading spaces in `999999` even when we use backticks so I have introduced punctuation marks to enforce representation.

Comment: Please, show us the code of your attempt to remove the space.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes....The statement is UPDATE tablename SET column name= ltrim(column name) where abc= '13712';

Comment: @APC.....it's a csv file and  to_number() is not working

Comment: We need to know what the leading characters are. Clearly they are not spaces. So use `select dump(column_name) from tablename` and post the output **in the question** not as a comment.

Comment: @apc... this is the output that I got -> Typ=1 Len=6: 57,57,57,57,57,57

Comment: That tells you **there are no leading characters**. You got six nines and nothing else. So, wherever those spaces are coming from it's not the data. What are you using to generate the CSV file?

Comment: Since the dump shows there are no leading chars in the data, the next question is 'what are you using to view your csv file?  If you are using anything other than a pure text editor like notepad, (say, you are opening the csv with excel) then it is a presentation issue with that program.

Comment: Is the CSV being produced from the same DB session where you did the update; and if not, have you committed that change?

Comment: @AlexPoole.....Yes, csv is being produced from the sam DB session. If I don't commit the changes will it make any changes in that?

Comment: Data on your table is without spaces, the issue is from export method to CVS or application you use to view CVS file. I suggest to use [CVSed](https://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html) editor.

Comment: i think that's the data issue in the table becuase when I'm trying to put in a format in this -> (888)-888 using regexp_replace, the format is not getting applied on that rest everything is going fine....

Comment: @JaspreetSingh - depends exactly what you're doing. If you explicitly commit in the session that did the update, does that affect the CSV output?

Comment: @AlexPoole....If I explicitly commit in the session i don't think so that will make any effect in csv output.

Answer (score 4):

The leading characters aren't spaces. If they were an unadorned `ltrim()` would remove them. So they must me something else. To find out we can use `dump()` to display the ascii values of all the characters in a string.

Spoiler alert: in the following example they will turn out to be tabs :)

```
with tab_name as (
    select chr(11)||chr(11)||'56789' as column_name from dual
    )
select dump(column_name)
from tab_name
/
```

gives us

```
Typ=1 Len=7: 11,11,53,54,55,56,57
```

So now we know what we're dealing with we can use `ltrim()` with an extra parameter to remove the leading tabs. So sure this will work we can cast it to a number:

```
with tab_name as (
    select chr(11)||chr(11)||'56789' as column_name from dual
    )
select to_number(ltrim(column_name, chr(11)))
from tab_name
/
```

---

Hmmmm, after I wrote this the OP posted the output from their `dump()` query:

```
Typ=1 Len=6: 57,57,57,57,57,57
```

That's six nines, there are no invisible leading characters. In other words, wherever the padding comes from it's not the data.

So this is an answer to a different question :(

Comment: Regardless, this helps 90%+ of the time.